# Jquery Draggable with more than one handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

Is it possible to have a `draggable` element with more than one handle?

I am initializing it twice, each time with a different handle param, but it doesn't work - only the first one works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should only pass the 'handle' param once, and it can either be a selector or an elements(/s).

So, to make it work with more than one handle:

```
$(elem).draggable({
    handle: '#handle1, #handle2',
});
```

More info / source: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggables/draggable

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Just have these handlers selectable.

For instance:

```
$(element).Draggable({handle:'.handler'});
```