# Is it possible to have two handles for sortable div?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({ handle: '.panel' });
```

I also want my `.panel-text` css class to behave as a handle for that selector sortable.

if it is possible how to do that?
Thanks in advance..

I found the solution here at the end: [Jquery Draggable with more than one handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435446/jquery-draggable-with-more-than-one-handle)
In case if anyone wants to use.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the `.panel` class to the `.panel-text` element.

Or, better yet, assign a `.handler` class to all elements that should be handlers and then rewrite your line like this:

```
 $( ".selector" ).sortable({ handle: '.handler' });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer...I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435446/jquery-draggable-with-more-than-one-handle

Comment: But I can't assign .handler class because my those two classes have different styles

Comment: You're welcome. :) If, however, my suggestion would work in this case, I'd appreciate it if you accepted my answer so people trying to solve a similar issue would benefit from it. Have a great one!